# Unauthorized in spring boot admin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

I wanted to control the microservices that are running in the Eureka server. I used spring-boot-admin for this, but I am getting the error on accessing the information about the Trace,Log etc...

The error I am getting is

> Error: {"timestamp":1489052472862,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource.","path":"/metrics"}

My dependencies are

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and none of the below properties worked

```
endpoints.info.id=information
endpoints.info.sensitive=false
endpoints.info.enabled=true
information.app.name=Actuator Example
information.app.description=Actuator Example
information.app.version=1.0.0
```

and the same thing is happening with all the end points like mappings, env and all accept health

Answer (score 39):

Setting `management.security.enabled=false` in the `application.properties` will disable the security on the endpoints.

Comment: This application property is not available anymore on the newest spring-security version (2.1+). Just as information for current readers

Answer (score 0):

It's better to setup security by credentials `username` and `password` for most of endpoints listed here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Exceptions from the rule are `health` and `info` endpoints which won't be protected by credentials.

You can set `username` and `password` in `application.properties` like that:

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. 
On my spring boot application we had a cors filter to block Http Head requests. So head requests cannot be accepted.

- Check Javascript console log and application log.
- Setting management.security.enabled=false in the application.properties also necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm of the opinion that disabling the security to all sensitive endpoints isn't the way to go.

I had this issue while accessing `/metrics` and [apparently](https://aboullaite.me/an-introduction-to-spring-boot-actuator/), I was missing the `spring-boot-starter-security` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding the dependency to my `pom.xml`, and assuming that I have the following on my `application.yml`

```
...
security:
    user:
        name: myActuatorUser
        password: myActuatorPwd
...
```

I was able to access my `/metrics` endpoint.