# Spring Actuator does not provide entry points

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get extra information about an spring application using Actuator. So, here is what i added to my dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When i run my application i got the following endpoints:

```
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.618[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:24.619[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.389[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@e94dcf: startup date [Wed Sep 27 02:35:21 GMT-12:00 2017]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.495[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/hey]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.HelloController.respond()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.497[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/send]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.MailController.send()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.501[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.501[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.587[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.587[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:25.649[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.203[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.203[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/env || /env.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.204[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/trace || /trace.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.205[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.207[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.get(java.lang.String)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.208[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.LoggersMvcEndpoint.set(java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.208[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/loggers || /loggers.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.209[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/info || /info.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.211[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.212[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/health || /health.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.security.Principal)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.213[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/mappings || /mappings.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.214[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/auditevents || /auditevents.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.AuditEventsMvcEndpoint.findByPrincipalAndAfterAndType(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.lang.String)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.215[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.215[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/metrics || /metrics.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.216[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.217[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/octet-stream]}" onto public void org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HeapdumpMvcEndpoint.invoke(boolean,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException,javax.servlet.ServletException
[2m2017-09-27 02:35:26.217[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m5128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/beans || /beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke
```

So, i would like to know what are the beans using the endpoint

```
http://localhost:8080/beans
```

but it complains with:

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

```
Wed Sep 27 02:41:33 GMT-12:00 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
Full authentication is required to access this resource.
```

So, what is wrong?

I don't have any security plugin in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you wrote:

> I don't have any security plugin in my code

As long as `spring-security` is on the classpath the actuator endpoints may be secured.

So either:

- Ensure that Spring Security is **not** on the classpath

Or

- Set this application property:

  ```
  management.security.enabled=false
  ```

Answer (score 1):

It has security by default. You can disable it in the application properties.

Please see: [Unauthorized in spring boot admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648060/unauthorized-in-spring-boot-admin)

Answer (score 0):

There are two way you can remove this error.

1 Way -> Update your @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation with below.

```
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

2 Way -> Follow [this](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/224887-how-to-disable-activiti-rest-http-basic-authentication) to disable authentication.